# Are unreachable objects safe from collection for any time after becoming unreachable?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, garbage-collection, objective-c++

I'm storing some Obj-C objects in a C++ data structure. Since I'm running under garbage collection and my objects are only reachable via the C++ structure, I'm calling CFRetain() to root each object added to the structure to ensure they aren't collected prematurely:

```
- (void) doSomethingFancyWithObjects:(NSArray*)array
{
    std::list<NSObject*> list;

    for (NSObject* obj in array)
    {
        id copyAddedToList = [obj copy];
        list.push_back(copyAddedToList);
        CFRetain(copyAddedToList); // otherwise list.back() becomes unreachable...
    }

    // ... //

    BOOST_FOREACH(NSObject* obj, list)
    {
        CFRelease(obj);
    }
}
```

Is it necessary to do this? Is there actually any chance that the GC will kick in and collect unreachable objects during the method in which they become unreachable? Can the GC collect at any time, or only at specific times such as the end of the run loop? Haven't managed to find a relevant bit of documentation on this.

Answer (score 1):

As posted in your code in which everything happens within the scope of `doSomethingFancyWithObjects:` you do not need the `CFRetain/CFRelease` pair because you are not removing the objects from `array` which is on the stack and therefore rooted.

**Edit**

OK, I didn't read the code properly - the objects are being copied.

Firstly, I would question the need for copying.  If you are modifying the objects in the list, why?  They are being thrown away at the end.

Secondly, you actually have a race condition.  The garbage collector could get in between `list.push_back([obj copy]);` and `CFRetain(list.back());` and then the object pointer in the `std::list` will be dangling.  You should do something like:

```
NSObject* theCopy = [obj copy];
CFRetain(theCopy);
list.push_back(theCopy);
```

Comment: the object in the list is not the same as the object in the array (it's copied out), so it's not rooted via the array.

Comment: @Chris: added some further comments.  In particular your code has a race condition.

Comment: If I do need to manually root list.back(), I'd better do it before it becomes unreachable then! Fixed, thanks. Re: your first point, this isn't my actual method, it's just the shortest example of the scenario that I could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

I found some info here:

[Garbage Collection Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/GarbageCollection/Articles/gcEssentials.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002452-SW1)

> In a standard application, Cocoa automatically hints at a suitable point in the event cycle that collection may be appropriate. The collector then initiates collection if memory load exceeds a threshold. Typically this should be sufficient to provide good performance. Sometimes, however, you may provide a hint to the collector that collection may be warranted—for example after a loop in which you create a large number of temporary objects. You can do this using the NSGarbageCollector method collectIfNeeded.

This seems to indicate that the garbage collector won't be run magically in the middle of functions (or simultaneously from another thread!), but only somewhere in the event cycle.

You're right, though, that in general it's important to retain objects in c++ if you don't want them to be garbage collected out from under you as is also stated in the document:

> In general, C++ code should remain unchanged: you can assume memory allocated from standard malloc zone. If you need to ensure the longevity of Objective-C objects, you should use CFRetain instead of retain.

**EDIT**

Oops, I discovered this more [illuminating part](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/GarbageCollection/Articles/gcArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002451-SW1) of the reference:

> The collector is both request and demand driven. The Cocoa implementation makes requests at appropriate times. You can also programmatically request consideration of a garbage collection cycle, and if a memory threshold has been exceeded a collection is run automatically.
>
> The collector runs on its own thread in the application.

So as Jeremy points out, the garbage collector can run in the middle of your function even if your function is in the main thread.

Comment: Good spot, hadn't noticed the first paragraph you quoted. But still, Apple use 'Event Cycle' to refer to the run loop of the main thread, so if that's what they mean here, I'd only have this guarantee when running on the main thread (and unfortunately, I'm not...)

Comment: Oh your function is running in another thread?  It seems like you should do the CFRetain then.  It's probably not a big deal compared to all the other fancy stuff you're doing with the objects!

Comment: The garbage collector runs in its own thread and it runs whenever it feels a GC is needed.  You can't assume it is not running in any one particular function.